# How to disable p5 canvas on button click

Tags: typescript, canvas, p5.js

I am using `p5.js` for drawing. I have used below code & it works fine for drawing.

```ts
sketch(p: any) {
    p.setup = function () {
      var canvas = p.createCanvas(700, 400);
      canvas.parent('sketchdiv');
      p.strokeWeight(5);
      p.stroke(0);
      p.windowWidth = 700;
      p.windowHeight = 400;
    };
    p.draw = () => {
      if (p.mouseIsPressed) {
        if (p.mouseButton === p.LEFT) {
          p.line(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, p.pmouseX, p.pmouseY);
        } else if (p.mouseButton === p.CENTER) {
          p.background(255);
        }
      }
    };

    p.mouseReleased = () => {
      // modulo math forces the color to swap through the array provided
      // this.strokeColor = (this.strokeColor + 1) % this.c.length;
      // p.stroke(this.c[this.strokeColor]);
      // console.log(`color is now ${this.c[this.strokeColor]}`);
      console.log("mouseReleased");
    };
}
```

But I have another canvas (which uses mouse press, rotation etc.) in bootstrap modal. When i do mouse rotation on bootstrap modal canvas, it draws in the background canvas also. I do not want to draw anything on main screen canvas when i am rotating on bootstrap canvas.

**How to do this ? Please Help / Guide.**

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but you can limit the scope of the mouse events to a specific canvas by assigning the related events to it:

```js
const sketchA = p => {
  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(60, 60)
    p.background(100)
  }
  
  p.mousePressed = () => {
    p.background(p.random(255), p.random(255),p.random(255))
  }
}

const sketchB = p => {
  p.setup = () => {
    const canvas= p.createCanvas(60, 60)
    p.background(100)
    
    canvas.mousePressed(
      () => {
        p.background(p.random(255), p.random(255),p.random(255))
      }
    )
  }
}

new p5(sketchA, document.getElementById("sk-a"))
new p5(sketchB, document.getElementById("sk-b"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label> Capture clicks in all the viewport </label>
  <div id="sk-a"></div>
<div>
<div>
  <label> Capture clicks in the canvas only </label>
  <div id="sk-b"></div>
</div>
```